# Navbar change in height not affecting active area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

To fit my logo the size I want it in the navbar, I increased the height of the fixed navbar at the top of the page to 80px. Problem now is that the height of the actively selected area hasn't changed with the nav bar.

[screencap of affected area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scZ1z.png)

My HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="active"><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="./about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="./products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="./contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="./jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="./clients.html">Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My custom CSS overwriting the bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/y1ycfbbr/

Comment: Dont give `height` instead try giving `padding-top`  and  `padding-bottom` to `navbar ul li a`.

Comment: Hey @Kate you got four answers, would be nice if you upvote the one which helped you. :-) If not, just talk to us! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like that the Navbar-Brand (Logo) overlaps the Navbar you could use absolute positioning like this:

```
.navbar-header {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example in this pen: [Absolute Position](http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/gMrZNx)

If would like to expand the navbar by the height of your logo you need to adjust the height of the navbar and the default paddings from the links of ".nav.navbar-nav" element. Easiest way to do this is using a precomplier like gulp using your own bootstrap variables or adjust the default bootstrap less variables on the customize page from bootstrap. [Customize Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less)

Example in this pen: [Same height of logo and navbar](http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/pbyGzQ)

Answer (score 0):

The outer div (.navbar) has more priority than the inner one (.navbar-brand), if you inspect the elements, you may see the Strikethrough of "height: 80px".
Try "!important"

Answer (score 0):

You should know exactly how bootstrap works (look at the css file)

```
    .navbar {
      min-height: 80px; // Default 50px 
    }

    .navbar-brand {
      height: 80px;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 30px; // Default 15px
      padding-bottom: 30px; // Default 15px
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo and the navigation buttons to be of the same height when they are displayed as a horizontal menu, the CSS below is what you can use.

The `@media` rule is there so that the new rules don't apply to small-screen devices (e.g. mobile phone) as navigation menu is displayed in vertical mode in those devices and you won't want your buttons to appear extra tall in a vertical menu.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .navbar {
    min-height: 80px; 
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    height: 80px !important;
  }
  .nav>li>a {
    padding: 15px 30px !important;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezZxJw

Comment: Please vote up if you find it helpful. Glad to be of help =) There is a up button on the left to each answer, you can vote up for more than one answers, in case you don't know